# changing file attribute in adobe air

Tags: filesystems, air

Is there a way to change the file attribute of a file in abobe air,for example :  like changing read only file or read write file or copying a "read only" file  to a new location a a "read write" file.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not a way to modify file attributes with AIR (as of v1.5).  You can always read a read-only file and write it to a new writable file though.

Comment: I think this was basically covered by a previous question, but could not locate it.